# Access JSON data without field name

Tags: android, json

I have a JSON data which is accessible through a link like http://192.55.23.210:8085/Services/getFriends?userId=xyz which returns an array like ["xyz","abc"]. How to access these objects

Comment: url is slow down, provide exact json data

Comment: You can get the field names do you know that If you have a JSONArray..

Comment: U will not be able to acees that link.. I have provided the dummy data

Answer (score 0):

You can get the field names without having to know them using `names(int)` method of `JSONObject` class, and then access them:

```
public void getFieldNames(JSONArray jsonArray) {
 List<String> fieldNames = new ArrayList<String>;
try {

for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); ++i) {
    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    fieldNames[i] = jsonObject.names(i); 

    }
} catch (Exception e) {
   Log.e("ConnectToDatabase->getJsonData", "Error Parsing JSON Data "
        + e.toString());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONParser parser=new JSONParser();
    String s="[\"xyz\",\"abc\"]";

    try {
        JSONArray jsonarray=(JSONArray)parser.parse(s);
        for (Object object : jsonarray) {
            System.out.println((String)object);
        }
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: @Sharp Edge Field names do not exist.. I have only an array as I have mentioned in the question

Comment: Here u r doing hardcoding by putting values xyz and abc.. I don't know values

Comment: well of-course this was example. so instead of hard coded string you can retrieve json data from url and parse it the same way i did.